# Excel Function/VBA to find value based on date time and two criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have measured data that contains occupancy data for a building. There are multiple rooms and multiple room areas within each room on each floor.The room number contains the floor in it so I do not need to search by floor.

And the occupancy data has a time stamp that recorded whenever there was activity in that specific area.

Basically, I want Excel to look and see if the room number and room area match and the time matches and then report whether or not that area was occupied or not.

I can only find INDEX MATCH where they search for multiple exact criteria, which is not applicable here since I need the closest match for time values.

Any help is greatly appreciated! I would be most interested in a Function that can accomplish this, but am open to VBA solutions as well.

Thank you!

Here is the link to the data

http://jmp.sh/v/D907ef9W3055ThlR1ssa

```
| Date / Time    | DATE     | TIME  | FLOOR | LAB    | LAB AREA | Occupancy (0 = unoccupied) |
|----------------|----------|-------|-------|--------|----------|----------------------------|
| 9/3/2015 10:30 | 9/3/2015 | 10:30 | 9     | 99400  | A        | 0                          |
| 9/3/2015 10:30 | 9/3/2015 | 10:30 | 10    | 109400 | D        | 0                          |
| 9/3/2015 10:30 | 9/3/2015 | 10:30 | 8     | 89400  | A        | 0                          |
| 9/3/2015 10:31 | 9/3/2015 | 10:31 | 10    | 109400 | D        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 10:36 | 9/3/2015 | 10:36 | 8     | 89400  | B        | 0                          |
| 9/3/2015 10:38 | 9/3/2015 | 10:38 | 8     | 89400  | A        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 10:40 | 9/3/2015 | 10:40 | 10    | 109410 | A        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 10:41 | 9/3/2015 | 10:41 | 15    | 159400 | A        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 10:52 | 9/3/2015 | 10:52 | 8     | 89400  | B        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 10:57 | 9/3/2015 | 10:57 | 8     | 89400  | E        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 11:20 | 9/3/2015 | 11:20 | 10    | 109410 | A        | 0                          |
| 9/3/2015 11:21 | 9/3/2015 | 11:21 | 17    | 179400 | D        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 11:21 | 9/3/2015 | 11:21 | 12    | 129400 | E        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 11:23 | 9/3/2015 | 11:23 | 10    | 109410 | A        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 11:26 | 9/3/2015 | 11:26 | 8     | 89400  | E        | 0                          |
| 9/3/2015 11:54 | 9/3/2015 | 11:54 | 8     | 89400  | C        | 0                          |
| 9/3/2015 14:10 | 9/3/2015 | 14:10 | 17    | 179400 | E        | 0                          |
| 9/3/2015 14:16 | 9/3/2015 | 14:16 | 12    | 129410 | B        | 0                          |
| 9/3/2015 14:17 | 9/3/2015 | 14:17 | 14    | 149410 | A        | 0                          |
| 9/3/2015 14:31 | 9/3/2015 | 14:31 | 17    | 179400 | E        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 14:38 | 9/3/2015 | 14:38 | 9     | 99400  | A        | 0                          |
| 9/3/2015 14:43 | 9/3/2015 | 14:43 | 14    | 149410 | A        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 14:47 | 9/3/2015 | 14:47 | 17    | 179400 | D        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 14:51 | 9/3/2015 | 14:51 | 9     | 99400  | A        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 14:56 | 9/3/2015 | 14:56 | 14    | 149410 | A        | 0                          |
| 9/3/2015 15:01 | 9/3/2015 | 15:01 | 10    | 109410 | A        | 0                          |
| 9/3/2015 15:04 | 9/3/2015 | 15:04 | 10    | 109410 | A        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 15:07 | 9/3/2015 | 15:07 | 14    | 149410 | A        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 15:15 | 9/3/2015 | 15:15 | 8     | 89400  | C        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 15:18 | 9/3/2015 | 15:18 | 12    | 129400 | E        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 15:22 | 9/3/2015 | 15:22 | 8     | 89400  | E        | 1                          |
| 9/3/2015 15:27 | 9/3/2015 | 15:27 | 17    | 179400 | D        | 0                          |
| 9/3/2015 15:27 | 9/3/2015 | 15:27 | 17    | 179400 | E        | 0                          |
```

Comment: Provide a data sample. Match can return an approximate match if the data is sorted. Any more detailed suggestion would require knowledge of your data structure. Hence, provide a data sample.

Comment: No problem. How/where can I post the data sample?

Comment: Use a file sharing service, edit your question and paste the link. Post a comment when you've done that.

Comment: Posted the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the screenshot below. For ease of understanding, the formula has been split up into several helper cells, but it can be constructed to work all in one cell (or with named ranges).

Sort the data first by Date/Time, then Lab area, then Lab.

```
firstRow       =MATCH(lab&Area,INDEX(FullTable[LAB]&FullTable[LAB AREA],0),0)
lastRow        =COUNTIFS(FullTable[LAB],lab,FullTable[LAB AREA],Area)+firstRow
TimeMatchRow   =MATCH(time,INDEX(FullTable[Date / Time],firstRow):INDEX(FullTable[Date / Time],lastRow),1)
occupancyValue =IF(INDEX(FullTable[Occupancy (0 = unoccupied)],firstRow+TimeMatchRow-1),"occupied","not occupied")
```

firstRow establishes the first row where the lab and area combination is found. Adding a count of the lab and area combo helps establish the last row of the range to use for an approximate lookup on the time value. With 1 as the last parameter, Match will return the next smallest value if no exact match is found. That is the row where the time match is found. Finally, using an Index on the occupancy column, adding the firstRow and the time match row and adjust by one.

[image]

Comment: That is great. Are you able to explain what you are doing a little more though please? I plugged in the numbers and everything works, but how did you come up with this? And would there be an equivalent way of performing this task if the dates weren't in chronological order?